# "cordova requirements" command gives error "windows os: not installed"

Tags: windows, cordova, build

When i am trying to check create windows build requirements it gives error "windows os: not installed"

Check by attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm asking because you need to run Windows to build for the windows platform, see the docs [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/).

Comment: Yes i am using windows 10.